# Get clicked item from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on a project where i'm using angular.

I got an array and i put that array in a list item and show the elements from that array

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Answers in Multiples">
         <button ng-click="addAnswer()">{{Answers}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now i want when i click on one of the buttons that it shows the value of that object.

```
$scope.addAnswer(){
   console.log('Item i clicked on');
}
```

Comment: `ng-click="addAnswer(Answers);"` and you have your `Answers` object in your `addAnswer` function as a parameter: `$scope.addAnswer(ans) { console.log(ans); }`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `j`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in the variable being iterated over:

```
<button ng-click="addAnswer(Answers)">{{Answers}}</button>
```

And use it:

```
$scope.addAnswer(answers){
    console.log('Item i clicked on', answers);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fast answer. I did get it working this way. Thanks alot!